# CSS - Не работают svg фильтры

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, svg

Почему svg фильтр работает только "для" body?

```css
/* Если сюда подставить body - работает, если #wrapper - не работает */

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: url(80kv_prev.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.object {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  background: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hide;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

#wrapper:before {
  visibility: visible;
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  background: inherit;
  width: 110%;
  height: 110%;
  left: -5%;
  top: -5%;
  -webkit-filter: url("#blur");
  -moz-filter: url("#blur");
  filter: url("#blur");
}
```

```html
<svg>
        <defs>
          <filter id="blur">
              <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4" />
           </filter>
        </defs>
      </svg>

<div id="background-wrapper"></div>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

В чем ошибка? Kак сделать так, чтобы размывалось всё, что находится под блоком `#wrapper`?

Comment: а просто css : `filter:blur();` уже не справляется ?

Comment: Этот вариант не подходит. Надо размыть все, что находится под размытым блоком. У вас есть решение просто через filter:blur();?

Comment: а что мешает сделать нужному элементу blur ?  вроде бы не сложно это

Comment: То что элементов может быть сотни и это занимает очень много ресурсов.

Comment: http://git.blivesta.com/oblurlay/  я уже 20 способов проверил и не один не работает , плюс от меня , по ссылке работающий пример